# Truncation of BG?

Tags: classifying-spaces, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a topological group. In some cases, e.g. when $G$ is discrete or when the spaces $G^n$ are locally contractible and the coefficients are discrete, the cohomology of the classifying space $BG$ is the group cohomology of $G$. So, for simplicity, let us assume that $G$ is discrete.

My question: is there a nice explicit space $B_{\leq k}G$ that is functorial in $G$, such that $H^n(B_{\leq k} G, M) = H^n (BG, M)$ for $n \leq k$ and $0$ for $n>k$? Here $M$ is a $G$-module.

For example, for $G = S^1$, $BG = CP^\infty$ and a possible choice for $B_{\leq 2} S^1$ is $CP^1$. (If it simplifies the question, feel free to assume $M = \mathbf Z$.)

Thank you.

(Edit: In response to Ralph's comment, let us assume $G$ is discrete to simplify, but an answer for non-discrete groups would be interesting, too.)

Comment: In general the cohomology of the topological space $BG$ doesn't equal the group cohomology of $G$. However, they agree if $G$ is discrete. 

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question accordingly, even though the agreement for $H^*(BG,-)$ and $H^*(G, -)$ also holds in other cases that I am (actually) interested in.

Comment: What are these cases where $H^\ast(BG,-)=H^\ast(G,-)$ you have in mind ? 

Comment: I was mostly thinking of $S^1$.

Comment: Note that $H^\ast(BS^1,-)\neq H^\ast(S^1,-)$ (where the latter is group cohomology). For example, $H^2(BS^1,\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{Q}$, while $H^2(S^1,\mathbb{Q})=Hom_\mathbb{Q}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Q})$ has as $\mathbb{Q}$-dimension the cardinality of the power set of the reals. An interesting paper that compares the homology of $BG$ and the group homology of $G$ for Lie groups $G$ is Milnor: On the homology of Lie groups made discrete. Comment. Math. Helv. 58(1983), 72-85. 

Comment: We may be talking about different kinds of group cohomology of a topological group? Do you refer to the one computed by means of continuous cochains? I am primarily interested in the one defined as the derived functor (and should have stated that right from the beginning, sorry). The two agree (if I understand it right) provided that the cohomology groups of the topological space $G^q$, $H^p(G^q, M)$, vanishes for all $p, q > 0$, because of the spectral sequence $$H^p (H^q (EG^*, M)) \Rightarrow H^n (G, M).$$ 
This condition is not satisfied though for $G = S^1$, $M = \mathbf Q$.

Comment: By group cohomology I mean $H^i(G;M)=Ext_{\mathbb ZG}^i(\mathbb{Z},M)$. What is $G^q$ ? 

Comment: $G^q = G \times \dots \times G$, $q$ factors. The $E_2$ terms in the previous comments, $H^p(G^q, M)$, are the cohomology of $G^q$ as a topological space (as opposed to group cohomology).

Comment: What is $\mathbb Z G$ for a topological group, e.g. $S^1$?

Comment: $\mathbb ZG$ is the usual group ring (integer linear combinations of elements of $G)$; it doesn't depend on the topology of $G$. // In the following I'll use $H^\ast_{top}$ to denote the (cellular) cohomology of a topological space and $H^\ast_{gr}$ for the group cohomology defined in my 4th comment. // If we mean  by "group cohomology" the same, then I think there are counterexamples to the statement in your 3rd comment: Set $Q := \mathbb{Q},\;R := \mathbb{R}$ and take $G=(R,+)$ with the usual (Euclidean) topology. $R$ is contractible, hence $H^p_{top}(R^q;Q)=0$ for $p,q>0$. 

Comment: ... Since $BR=\{\ast\}$, $H^1_{top}(BR,Q)=0$ while $H^1_{gr}(R,Q)=Hom(R,Q)=Hom_Q(R,Q)=Q^R$. 

Comment: OK, so this shows the two notions of group cohomology are indeed different: if the group acts trivially on $M$, then $H^1(G, M)$ (defined by means of the derived functor of the global section functor) agrees with $Hom_{continuous}(G, M)$ (as it should, I am inclined to say). Thus, in the example you mention, $H^1(\mathbb R, \mathbb Q) = 0$, as opposed to $\mathbb Q^\mathbb R$.

Anyway, thank you for your patient explanations!

Comment: I don't think that the statement in your 3rd comment is true as stated, irregardless of the notion of group cohomology: Take in my example above $R$ as trivial coefficients. Then still $H^1_{top}(BR,R)=0$ while either $Hom(R,R)\neq 0$ and $Hom_{continuous}(R,R)\neq 0$ since both contain $id_R$. 

Comment: Do you mean the spectral sequence is wrong? I was referring to Flach's paper "Cohomology of topological groups ..." www.math.caltech.edu/~flach (who quotes SGA 4) here, who also shows that $H^1(\mathbf R, \mathbf R) = \Hom_{cont.}(\mathbf R, \mathbf R)$. The agreement of this group cohomology $H^n(G, A)$ with $H^n(BG, A)$ is also from that paper for _discrete_ coefficient modules $A$. So, yes, $0 = H^1_{top}(BR, R) \neq H^1(R, R) = \mathbf R$, but taking $\mathbf Z$-coefficients, both sides agree (=0) or similarly with $\mathbf R$-coefficients, when $\mathbf R$ is regarded as a discrete group.

Comment: (cont). More precisely, the agreement $H^n(BG, A) = H^n(G, A)$ between group coho. and singular cohomology of BG is shown in loc. cit. (Prop 5.2) if the spaces $G^n$ are locally contractible and $A$ is discrete and has trivial $G$-action. I believe that the locally-contractible condition is unnecessary if one takes sheaf cohomology of $BG$ instead, but for $G = \mathbf R$ there is no difference.

Comment: I think the point is that the assumption $H^p(G^q,M)=0$ for $p,q>0$ from your 3rd comment implies that $H^p(G,M)=H^p\Gamma(G^\ast,M)$ (Prop. 5.1), but the latter agrees with $H^p_{top}(BG,M)$ in general only if $M$ is discrete with trivial G-action. Anyway, it has been interesting to learn about Grothendieck's cohomology theory of topological groups. Thanks for this. 


Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several functorial models for $BG$, see for example [Adem, Milgram: Cohomology of Finite Groups, Chapter II] where 
$$BG = \coprod_{i=0}^\infty \sigma^i \times G^i/(\text{relations})$$
with $\sigma^i=\lbrace (x_1,...,x_i)\mid 0\le x_1 \le \cdots \le x_i \le 1\rbrace$ the standard $i$-simplex.

Now assume $G$ is discrete. Then $$B_nG := \coprod_{i=0}^n \sigma^i \times G^i/(\text{relations})$$ 
is the n-skeleton of $BG$ and depends functorially on $G$. Since the cohomology in degree $\lt n$ of a CW complex is determined by the $n$-skeleton, we obtain $H^k(B_nG;M)=H^k(BG;M)$ for $0 \le k < n$ and $H^k(B_nG;M)=0$ for $k> n$ and all (local) coefficients $M$.

In general $H^n(B_nG;M)\neq H^n(BG;M)$, but there is an exact sequence: Write $BG=EG/G$ $(EG$ is described explicitely in Adem-Milgram) and let $E_nG$ be the $n$-skeleton of $EG$. Then the following sequence is exact (Cartan, Eilenberg: Homologica Algebra, XVI, §9, Appl. 1): 
$$0 \to H^n(BG;M)\to H^n(B_nG;M)\to H^n(E_nG;M)^G \to H^{n+1}(BG;M)\to 0$$

**Remark:** In case that $G$ is not discrete, the above has to be adjusted accordingly. For example, if $G$ is (topologically) a $m$-dimensional CW complex then $B_nG$ is the $n(m+1)$-skeleton of $BG$.

Comment: I took the liberty to editing it: I changed a "<" to \lt.  It seems to have done the trick.


Comment: Thank you, Ralph! This might be as close as one can get. A question concerning your last remark: for $G=S^1$, you say that $B_1 S^1 = S^1$ is the 2-skeleton of $BS^1 = CP^\infty$. Is there some typo here--I don't see how that can be true. I expect $sk_2 CP^\infty = CP^1$, instead. 

Comment: I get $B_1S^1=\lbrace \ast\rbrace \; \coprod\; [0,1]\times S^1/\sim$ with the relations $$[0,1] \times 1 \sim \lbrace \ast\rbrace,\;0 \times S^1 \sim \lbrace \ast\rbrace,\;1\times S^1\sim \lbrace\ast\rbrace$$
This looks to me like $B_1S^1=S^2\cong CP^1$. 